# Changing Naming Convention in Data Grip

Tags: sql, db2, naming-conventions, datagrip

How can I change the naming convention for a SQL script while using a IBM DB2 Database?

In my RPG(LE) programs I can simply code

```
exec sql set option naming=*sql;
```

to change from `MYLIB/TESTPF` to `MYLIB.TESTPF` and

```
exec sql set option naming=*sys;
```

back again to `MYLIB/TESTPF`. As it seems in `SQLRPGLE` it doesn't matter which naming convention I use. The compiler accepts both (the `MYLIB/TESTPF` and `MYLIB.TESTPF`) as long as either I include only `set option naming=*sys;` before my first SQL statement or no `SET OPTION` at all.

But DataGrip just accepts the `*SQL` convention. Even if I open `File->Data Source->Select Data Source->Advanced Tab->` and set `naming` to `system`.

I also tried writing `SET OPTION naming=*sys` in the SQL Editor. But there is no Code Completion after `SET`. It just allows me to SET `SERVER OPTION`, but there is no "naming".

Thanks!

Comment: In Datagrip, which driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using DB2 (JTOpen)

Comment: Maybe ask the vendor? Via their community forum https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200381555-DataGrip

Answer (score 0):

I asked JetBrains and they said "This is not possible". But they already have a RFE on their bugtracker YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2523), which the supporter has provided to me.

Hope, they implement this soon.